# Style sheet (CSS ) protection from public

Tags: html, css

We need to protect my external style sheet downloading from others

eg: if click the save as button from a browser that will get all images, html and style sheet of the website. we need to block downloading my website images, html and CSS

how is it possible

please help me .......

Comment: whats the poin of doing that?

Comment: This is theoretically impossible. You can do things like obfuscation - minify and change the names of classes and things like that. But the actual HTML or CSS cannot be hidden otherwise web browsers will be unable to display the pages.

Comment: So you're saying you don't want to display your all images, html, and style of your website to your users? How will the browser display it without the markup and know how to style it without the css? If you really want to be a pain, your webpage should be one image file and only display the one image ;)

Comment: Why is this question voted down? It is a valid question with a negative answer. Just requires a simple explanation of how the browser works.

Comment: no one is interested in your CSS, trust me.

Comment: As for images, if your images are valuable and copyrighted work, the best protection is a good lawyer :)

Answer (score 14):

That is technically impossible and illogical. Your HTML, CSS and images need to be available to everyone that can access the site, otherwise they wouldn't be able to view them in the first place. And by definition, you have no control over the client's browser which handles the downloading and saving of said resources.

By the way, there are some tricks employed by people wanting to do the same (like using Javascript to block the right click menu) but such tricks are just that: Tricks. They trick the naive user into thinking that some resources can't be downloaded/saved. However such tricks are easily circumvented by a user with very little knowledge.

Answer (score 7):

HTML, Javascript and CSS code are by definition provided to the user as source code.

This is not like a compiled desktop application where the user cannot see the code behind the scenes -- all web pages are provided as source code. There is nothing you can do about this.

It is possible to make it hard to read by minifying it, although this trick works better with Javascript than it does with CSS. But the primary goal of minifying is not to make it unreadable, but to make it smaller for download; the fact that it becomes hard to read to read is more of a side-effect.

If you really are paranoid about people stealing your hard work, then bluntly, HTML+JS+CSS is the wrong platform for you. You might be able to hide your code more effectively with Flash or Silverlight, though to be honest, even in these, it is possible for a relatively skilled hacker to unpick them and get at the code.

But the fact is that HTML and CSS code are never going to be valuable assets. They are far too simple to produce anything radically unusual; everything in your HTML and CSS code will already exist in countless other sites, so your code isn't going to be worth stealing, and even if it is, it isn't worth protecting.

The same applies even Javascript code. If there might be some justification in wanting to protect Javascript if you've written something spectacularly complex and unusual, but for the majority of sites, even the JS code isn't going to be complex enough to be worth protecting.

Answer (score 3):

How should any user be able to view the content you provide without prior downloading it?

Its not possible... :(

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is minimize it and maybe there is a css obfuscator out there.

Comment: Is it really possible to obfuscate CSS? How?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers must be able to understand the CSS in order to render the page. So, it is not possible to protect the CSS from downloading, because if you want the page to work, **the browser must download it**.

Comment: The browser will be able to render the page without the user's CSS file. Browsers have their own default styling.

Comment: @ngen: true, but I don't think anyone will classify a page that is missing css as something that is working, as you will only see the content